# What is the correct way to map an IPagedList<> using automapper

Tags: .net-core, automapper

## Intro

I have 2 AutoMapperProfiles that each have a mappings for a `Tag` entity the tag entity is nothing special, it just has an id an name. There also is a interface called `IPagedList<T> : IList<T>` and the class inheriting it called `PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>`. As for the mapping it goes as followed. (domain entity) Tag -> TagDto and TagDto -> TagViewModel. So nothing out of the ordinary.

## Code and my attempts

```cs
public class PagedList<T> : List<T>, IPagedList<T>
{
    ...

    /// <summary>
    /// Ctor
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="source">source</param>
    /// <param name="pageIndex">Page index</param>
    /// <param name="pageSize">Page size</param>
    /// <param name="totalCount">Total count</param>
    public PagedList(IEnumerable<T> source, int pageIndex, int pageSize, int totalCount)
    {
        TotalCount = totalCount;
        TotalPages = TotalCount / pageSize;

        if (TotalCount % pageSize > 0)
            TotalPages++;

        PageSize = pageSize;
        PageIndex = pageIndex;
        AddRange(source);
    }
    ...
}
```

### automapper Tag -> TagDto

```cs
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<Tag, TagDto>()
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap(typeof(IPagedList<>), typeof(IPagedList<>))
            .ConvertUsing(typeof(PagedListConverter<,>));
    }
}
```

### Automapper TagDto -> TagViewModel

```cs
public class AutoMapperProfile : Profile
{
    public AutoMapperProfile()
    {
        CreateMap<TagDto, TagViewModel>()
            .ReverseMap();

        CreateMap(typeof(IPagedList<>), typeof(IPagedList<>))
            .ConvertUsing(typeof(PagedListConverter<,>));
    }
}
```

In these classes you can see that I tried to create a [Custom Type Converters](https://docs.automapper.org/en/stable/Custom-type-converters.html) that would handle the mapping. The following code shows an example of when the mapping is suppose to be used:

### File: TagService

```cs
...
    public async Task<IPagedList<TagDto>> GetAllAsync(
        int pageIndex = 0,
        int pageSize = int.MaxValue,
        bool getOnlyTotalCount = false 
    )
    {
        var result = await PagedList<Tag>.CreateAsync(
            _tagRepository.Table,
            pageIndex,
            pageSize,
            getOnlyTotalCount
        );

        return _mapper.Map<IPagedList<TagDto>>(result);
    }
...
```

However when I debug this inside the `PagedListConverter`. whose code you can see below

```cs
public class PagedListConverter<TSource, TDestination> : ITypeConverter<IPagedList<TSource>, IPagedList<TDestination>>
{
    public IPagedList<TDestination> Convert(IPagedList<TSource> source, IPagedList<TDestination> destination, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        // Map the individual items from the source list to the destination type
        var destinationItems = context.Mapper.Map<IEnumerable<TSource>, IEnumerable<TDestination>>(source);

        // Create a new IPagedList<TDestination> instance using the mapped items
        var destinationPagedList = new PagedList<TDestination>(
            destinationItems,
            source.PageIndex,
            source.PageSize,
            source.TotalCount
        );

        return destinationPagedList;
    }
}
```

However I never end up in that converter. My suspision is because that the mapping would technically be a PagedList to an IPagedList. I am not certain of this, given that the PagedList obviously implements the IPagedList interface. Now in this example I only used the Tag. I would preferably like something generic. What would be the correct way to map in this case? How do others do this?

Here is an error that I get when the mapping fails:

```
AutoMapper.AutoMapperMappingException: Cannot create an instance of type Portfolio.Application.Mapper.PagedListConverter`2[Portfolio.Core.Domain.Tags.Tag,Portfolio.Application.Tags.TagDto]
   at lambda_method29(Closure, Object, IPagedList`1, ResolutionContext)
   at Portfolio.Application.Tags.TagService.GetAllAsync(Int32 pageIndex, Int32 pageSize, Boolean getOnlyTotalCount) in C:\<...>\src\Libraries\Portfolio.Application\Tags\TagService.cs:line 32
```

Comment: There are many similar questions.